# Is there a professional name for deciding which information should to be show in a website, it's not IA

Tags: website-design, content

It's not IA(information architecture). cos IA decide how to organize information, not to decide which information should be show in a website.

Answer (score 3):

You're probably looking for [content strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_strategy). If it's an *existing* site, it might be closer to a content audit(alternately content analysis or inventory), which is often a step of overall content strategy anyway.